# Example for addLiquidity method of UniswapV2 Router

Tags: blockchain, uniswap

I am reading through UniswapV2 docs and can't understand the inputs of `addLiquidity` method properly.
As listed in the [docs](https://docs.uniswap.org/protocol/V2/reference/smart-contracts/router-02#addliquidity):

> `amountAMin` (uint):  Bounds the extent to which the B/A price can go up before the transaction reverts. Must be <= amountADesired.
>
> `amountBMin` (uint):  Bounds the extent to which the A/B price can go up before the transaction reverts. Must be <= amountBDesired.

What does it mean? Can you please give an example? Let's say, I set `amountADesired` and `amountBDesired` to 4 and `amountAMin` and `amountBMin` to 1. What will happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

blockchain transactions **are not immediate**, but must queue before being mined on the blockchain and be effective

When you add liquidity given `amountADesired` you have to give it `amountBDesired` in proportion to the existing pair (example pair: 2:1 you have to put 2 tokens A and 1 token B)

once you send the transaction, before it is mined it may happen that others make operations on that liquidity pool, changing the proportion accordingly

by entering `amountAmin` and `amountBmin` you are practically telling him: "as long as the proportion is between `amountADesired`:`amountBDesired` and `amountAMin`:`amountBmin` accepts my liquidity addition, if instead the proportion exceeds my range, cancel my transaction"